# Script to Open URL as HTTP POST request (not just GET) in web browser

Tags: linux, windows, macos, http, shell

How can I open a URL from the command line script as a POST request to a URL? I'd like to to do this on Linux, Windows, and MacOS so a cross platform way of doing this

For each of these I can open a GET request to a URL using:

- `xdg-open [url]` - Linux
- `start [url]` - Windows
- `open [url]` - MacOS

... but I don't see a way of doing a POST request. Is it possible, and if so how?

Also, showing how to add a POST body to the request would be appreciated too. Fyi, the script I'm writing is written in Ruby so anything built-in to the OS or something using Ruby is fine too.

#### UPDATED:

To clarify I'd like this open up in the default browser, not just issue the POST request and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but there's no reliable way to do this across browsers and across operating systems. This was a topic the IE team spent a bunch of time looking into when we built Accelerators in IE8.

The closest you can come is writing a HTML page to disk that has an auto-submitting form (or XmlHttpRequest), then invoking the browser to load that page which will submit the form. This constrains your code to only submitting forms that are legal to submit from the browser (e.g. only thee possible content types, etc).

Comment: Yeah I thought it might not be possible. Thanks though. If anybody else wants to try something similar the work around I'm using is to do a POST via ruby to the server, return back an expiring unique id, and then issue a GET on that unique ID. Not quite as elegant as a direct POST but it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ruby you can use the `NET::HTTP` library: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd like it to open in the web browser, not just issue the request. I've updated the question description to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how compatible my solution is across browsers and platforms.

But instead of using a temporary file as described by @EricLaw,
you can encode that html with the auto-submit form in a Data URL, as i did here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1281950/open-chrome-with-method-post-body-data-on-specific-url/1631277#1631277